# How I can move a WSL to a virtual machine?

Tags: vmware, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed WSL on my windows 10 pro and installing a lot of libraries and executing commands. I created a virtual machine and I want to move the WSL to that blank hard. Can I really do that? and How?

Comment: You cannot;  However, you can enable WSL within the VM

Comment: Thank a lot, However, please mention to me, how I can enabling it?

Comment: The same way you enabled it on the physical machine.  I presume the VM is running a compatible version of Windows.

Comment: Yes, it is. Thanks

Comment: Alternatively, you can do a P2V conversion of your Windows 10 pro installation and run it on the VM with WSL. Might help: https://www.starwindsoftware.com/v2v-help/PhysicalDisksandP2VScenario.html